# before:(all) execution in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to forcefully stop the execution of `before:(all)` and the corresponding `it` blocks in a test framework developed using Rspec?

```
before:(all) do
  @test = check()
  if @test
  end
end
```

The check function returns `true` or `false`. If `false` is returned, then the corresponding examples should not get executed. How to do this?

Comment: Did you try doing: `before(:all){ } if check` But this won't stop execution of `it` blocks under `describe` or `context` block, you must do that at each context block level. However, if you tell us what you're actually trying to do then someone at SO might give you a good suggestion instead.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems like you want to stop executing tests if the `check` is `false`:

```
before(:all) do
  unless check
    puts 'Check failed, stopping test suite...'
    exit
  end 
end
```

`exit` initiates the termination of a Ruby script by raising the `SystemExit` exception

Comment: before(:all) is present in a loop. So if the check function returns false, then the tests should not be executed and the next iteration should continue. How to do this?

Comment: Please describe what you try to achieve. What does you `check` method check and why do you expect method return to `true` after it returned `false`. An example of your use case might help to understand your problem.